# Autorotation in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, xcode4.5

I am updating my app for iOS 6 and having issues with the changes to autorotation. My app has a bunch of view controllers and all of them should only support the portrait layout except 1 which should support all 3 orientations except upside down.

If I add the `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` method to the app delegate do I have to add conditions there to check if im displaying the one VC I want to be able to rotate?

The documentation states that if I implement `supportedInterfaceOrientations` on a VC it should override the app delegate method but this doesn't appear to be the case. I have an log statement in the method on the child VC and it is called once when the VC loads but its not called when I rotate the device, but the method in the app delegate is.

If I completely remove the method from the app delegate the orientation of my VC's seems to be completely dependent on my apps supported interface orientation settings. This of course seems to be due to the method `supportedInterfaceOrientations` being called once on creation of the VC but never when the device is rotated.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is almost my same exact question, I can't believe Apple made such a mess of the auto-rotation!  Did you resolve this issue?  If you could publish your notes it would be a great reference!

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to what @rooster117 had suggested. In my AppDelegate I overrode the method `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` and returned `[[(UINavigationController *)window.rootViewController visibleViewController] supportedInterfaceOrientations]`. This forced the top View Controller to supply the orientation info. Then implemented `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in each of my View Controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to override - (BOOL) shouldAutorotate and return "YES". This makes it so you declare what orientations your VC supports with "supportedInterfaceOrientations" and then on rotation it should call "shouldAutorotate". If you have any navigation controller or tabbar you may need to subclass those to do the same thing within them. I had this issue recently myself.

Comment: i forgot to mention, i did implement this method and its never called on my view controllers. all of my view controllers are managed by a few navigation controllers, do i really need to subclass my nav controllers for no other reason than to support custom rotation? seems like if that's the case apple really over-complicated something that worked before..

Comment: I had the same problem as you and basically it seems the parents (your navigation controllers) don't consult with their children (your VC's) if they don't support auto rotation themselves. Maybe there is a better way now or in the future but its really not too hard to do it this way.

Comment: I subclassed my nav controller and added 'shouldAutorotate' to it and just returned yes always. The rotation methods still aren't being called on the child VC's. Theres also a method 'shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods' that I tried on the nav controller and just returned yes. It gets called during rotation but doesn't seem to affect the child VC's. I'm at a loss..

Comment: Well don't give up. I struggled with it too and it was one of them that I was missing. If I were you I'd make a quick change to get a base case working with just one VC, then add the nav controller and work on that.

Comment: So clearly I'm misunderstanding something. I made a blank project with 1 nav controller and 1 view controller. the app delegate returns UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown for application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:. The nav controller and view controller both return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait for supportedInterfaceOrientations and regardless of if they return yes or no for shouldAutorotate it still rotates.

Comment: so I believe I found the real answer and sorry for semi-misleading you. You set up the structure with the top navigation controller returning autorotate not as "YES" but rather "return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;" which passes the question on to the navigation controller's top viewcontroller. This is what used to be automatic in iOS5 and earlier.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16934/discussion-between-rooster117-and-scott-f)

Comment: shouldAutorotate is deprecated in iOS6. Check out WWDC 2012 Session 236 for more details on this.

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is deprecated but "- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);" is what you use for ios6

Answer (score 13):

Replace
`[window addSubview:viewController.view];`
with
`window.rootViewController = viewController;`

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))  
    { 
        // here to  implement landscope code
    }
    else
    {  
        // here to  implement setframePortrait
    }
}
```